# Is it possible to use Metal shader code in an iPad Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, ipad, swift-playground, metal

Is it possible to use custom Metal shader code in an iPad Swift Playground?

If so, how does one get the *.metal file or code (or its pre-compiled object) onto an iPad to use with a Playground and Swift code?  Is the use of Xcode on a Mac required to help?

(this question is not about using the built-in performance shaders, or about running stuff in a Playground on a Mac)

Answer (score 6):

You have two options: either create an iOS playground in Xcode and send it to your iPad but then you are not allowed to edit the .metal file, just read it, like in [this example](http://metalkit.org/2016/07/31/metal-performance-shaders-for-the-ipad-playground.html); or you can create your shaders file as a multiline string (now possible in Swift 4 and Xcode 9 beta) and create your library from that string. A more cumbersome way is to concatenate string lines in Xcode 8/Swift 3 like in [this example](http://metalkit.org/2016/10/01/using-metalkit-part-2-3-2.html).